# Integral of a function with two variables problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I have the following integrable function: $$f(x,y):[1,\infty)^{2}\to\left[-1,1\right]$$ and we know that: $$\frac{1}{n}\int_{1}^{n}\int_{1}^{n}f\left(x,y\right)dxdy\to0$$ we need to prove that for every $\beta > 0$ it holds: $$\frac{1}{n^{1+2\beta}}\int_{1}^{n}\int_{1}^{n}x^{\beta}y^{\beta}f\left(x,y\right)dxdy\to0$$ I thin it can be solved with some integral inequality which I am not familiar with, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Holder's inequality may be useful, although a direct application does not give a useful bound

Comment: you may rearrange the integral as $$ \frac{1}{n} \int_1^n\int_1^n ({\frac{x}{n}})^\beta({\frac{y}{n}})^\beta f(x,y) dxdy$$ and  use the fact that $0\le({\frac{x}{n}})^\beta,({\frac{x}{n}})^\beta\le1$

Comment: @uditnarayanpandey Maybe you should post that as an answer... It perfectly answered the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may rearrange the integral as $$ \frac{1}{n} \int_1^n\int_1^n ({\frac{x}{n}})^\beta({\frac{y}{n}})^\beta f(x,y) dxdy$$ where  $0\le({\frac{x}{n}})^\beta,({\frac{x}{n}})^\beta\le1$.

Now see that since $\frac{1}{n}\int_{1}^{n}\int_{1}^{n}f\left(x,y\right)dxdy\to0 \Rightarrow$ for some $\epsilon >0 $, $\exists N \; \epsilon \; \Bbb{N}$ such that

$|\frac{1}{n}\int_{1}^{n}\int_{1}^{n}f\left(x,y\right)dxdy|<\epsilon, \ \forall \ n>N$.

Now since $\ 0\le({\frac{x}{n}})^\beta,({\frac{x}{n}})^\beta\le1 \ \Rightarrow \ |\frac{1}{n} \int_1^n\int_1^n ({\frac{x}{n}})^\beta({\frac{y}{n}})^\beta f(x,y) dxdy|< \epsilon \ ,\forall\ n>N$

$ \ \ \ \ \ \  \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n} \int_1^n\int_1^n ({\frac{x}{n}})^\beta({\frac{y}{n}})^\beta f(x,y) dxdy\ \to 0 $

Comment: I don't get the step where you deduce that the rearranged integral is smaller than epsilon, this is true if the sign of the function doesn't change  but $f$ can be both positive and negative.

Comment: That's why i used | |, the absolute value of the integral and utilized the fact that limit is 0